# Access VBA: Get Recordset from an embedded form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to access a value within a continuous form, and then pass that to a new form that is opened. I got this working properly, but it only works if the original form is open directly. It fails if I try and run this when the form is embedded within another form.

The error I get is;

> Run-Time error '2450': MS access cannot find the referenced
> 'ViewerForm'

The code I am using is; (courtesy of here: [Get Control or Recrdset Value on Continous Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319485/get-control-or-recrdset-value-on-continous-form))

```
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set r = Forms![ViewerForm].RecordsetClone 'Clone the recordset
r.Bookmark = Forms![ViewerForm].Bookmark 'Navigate to the active record
Myvalue = r!TagMain.Value
```

Why does the code work when I am opening the form by itself, yet fails when it is embedded within another form? Do I have to tell it the path through, to find the embedded form, such as

```
Forms![FormTheViewerIsEmbeddedWithin]![ViewerForm].RecordsetClone
```

Instead of

```
Forms![ViewerForm].RecordsetClone
```

Comment: The answer is yes to "Do I have to tell it the path.." Why not try it? What is name of your subform control?

Comment: I did try it, changing it to Forms![MultiViewerForm]![ViewerForm].RecordsetClone, but I get an error saying 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by my question was am I misunderstanding how to define the path, not whether I literally have to tell it the path or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewerForm` is the subform control on the main form. The control has no `RecordsetClone`.

You need the (sub)form that's inside it:

```
Forms![FormTheViewerIsEmbeddedWithin]![ViewerForm].Form.RecordsetClone
```

If you get the error `MS access cannot find the referenced 'ViewerForm'`, your subform control has a different name than the subform. Check its properties in the main form.

Comment: Ah, That makes much more sense. Thank you!